# python change global string in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

First off i am very new to coding and python. I am trying to call a global string inside of a function. Then I want to change it into an integer. Next, I want to apply some Math to the integer. Finally I want to convert that integer back to a string and send it back to the global to use in other functions.

I have accomplished most of what I needed to do, but I am having trouble sending the string back to the global. I have tried using return() but it just quits the program. Instead I want it to go to another function, while retaining the new value

Relevant code

```
current_gold = '10'

def town():
    global current_gold
    print(current_gold)

def pockets():
    global current_gold
    new_gold = int(current_gold) + 5
    new_gold = str(new_gold)
    print(new_gold.zfill(3))


    input("\tPress Enter to return to town")
    town()
```

This is not the full code. I maybe doing stuff drastically wrong though.

Comment: you're never changing *`current_gold`*. Also, it doesn't make much sense to have a *number* as a *string*. Why not have `current_gold = 10` and format it on output only with `zfill` or `.format`?

Comment: Not only does your code not change `current_gold` as you wrote it and Antti had mentioned, but im trying to understand why you need to convert it back and forth from string to ints.  It doesnt make sense that you do that

Comment: Ill try streamlining that way. But how do you change the value of a global string inside a function and carry it to another function? Would it be better to export/import it from a separate file?

Comment: I was getting a zfill error when it was left as an int. I fool around with that some more

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't use globals. You should pass the value into the functions and return the result. But if you insist, once you've declared it `global` in the function, you can simply `current_gold = ...` in the function to update it.

Answer (score 0):

```
current_gold = '10'
def changeToInt():
    global current_gold
    current_gold = int(current_gold)

print(type(current_gold)) # It's a string right now
changeToInt() # Call our function
print(type(current_gold)) # It's an integer now
```

Or you could do it by passing a parameter to your function like so:

```
current_gold = '10'
def changeToInt2(aVariable):
    return int(aVariable)

print(type(current_gold)) # It's a string right now
current_gold = changeToInt2(current_gold) # make current_gold the output of our function when called with current_gold as aVariable
print(type(current_gold)) # It's an int now
```